# How to find the size of the compressed image?

Tags: windows-10, compression, jpeg

So, if I have an image in BMP file format being 1024 x 768  and 8 bits (bit depth), I can get the size of the image: 1024 x 768 x 8 = 6,291,456; 6,291,456 / 8 x 1024 = 768 Kb, which is correct when I right click on an image and see its size.

Now, if I do the same thing with a JPG or PNG image, I don't get the same file size because JPG and PNG are compressed formats and thus have smaller file sizes.

Is there a way that I can find how much are those JPG and PNG images compressed? Like a percentage value maybe?

Comment: To figure that out you would need to know the size of the original image before compression as this info is not stored in the meta data.

Comment: Further, because the original image may have also been compressed in some form, you cannot know with any certainty the original size and therefore you cannot tell the percentage of compression.

Comment: Similar question>>>>>>https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/88167/is-it-possible-to-find-out-what-compression-ratio-was-used-for-a-particular-jpeg

Comment: All you can do is determine compression "level" but this is not the same as percentage>>>>https://www.imgonline.com.ua/eng/determine-jpeg-quality.php